# Write an equation in R and store the result in a vector

Tags: r

Here is the equation

[image]

This is what i have thought so far. I am not sure if this is correct.

```
result <- vector("double", 10)
for (t in 3:-1) {
  for (d in 0:1) {
    print(((exp(1)^(1 * (t - d))) / (1 + exp(1)^(t - d))))
  }
}
```

I also want to store these values in a vector. How can i do that?

Comment: I am sorry I am still new to R. I will learn about indentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```r
result <- vector("double", 10)
i <-  0
for (t in 3:-1) {
  for (d in 0:1) {
    i <- i + 1
    result[i] <- ((exp(1)^(1 * (t - d))) / (1 + exp(1)^(t - d)))
    print(((exp(1)^(1 * (t - d))) / (1 + exp(1)^(t - d))))
  }
}
#> [1] 0.9525741
#> [1] 0.8807971
#> [1] 0.8807971
#> [1] 0.7310586
#> [1] 0.7310586
#> [1] 0.5
#> [1] 0.5
#> [1] 0.2689414
#> [1] 0.2689414
#> [1] 0.1192029

result
#>  [1] 0.9525741 0.8807971 0.8807971 0.7310586 0.7310586 0.5000000 0.5000000
#>  [8] 0.2689414 0.2689414 0.1192029
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>